# Php + mysql построение графика - PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, highcharts

Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт не дописывал даты? Чтобы внизу был указанный диапазон дат 2017-07-01...2017-07-21(вот так). А то получается, что если значений больше чем дат, то скрипт дописывает даты, а это не нужно.

```
<div id="container" style="height: 600px; width: 900px"></div>

var cats = [];
var data = [];
$.get("http://test.controlcash.ru/get.php", function(resp){
  for (i=0; i<resp.length; i++) {
    cats.push(resp[i].x); 
    data.push(resp[i].y); 
  }
}).done(function() {
   chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(cats);
   chart.series[0].setData(data);        
})

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    marginBottom: 80
  },
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      rotation: 90
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [0]        
  }]
});
```

get.php:

```
 <?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("db_host", "db_user", "db_pass", "db_name");
    if ($result = mysqli_query($db, "select name, click from chart")) {
        while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){
            $array[]=array("x"=>$obj->name, "y"=>(int)$obj->click);
        }
        /* очищаем результирующий набор */
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    mysqli_close($db);

    $ar_js = json_encode($array);
    header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2017 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    echo $ar_js;
    ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите пример jsonа с несовпадающим количеством дат-значений

Comment: примерно так, т.е. должно быть всегда только две даты начальная и конечная, а этот компонент добавляет еще столько дат сколько и цифр
[array(23,45,56,76), array(2017-07-21, 2017-07-21)]

Comment: Какой результат ожидается для приведенных данных?

Comment: сделал правку и добавил фото- результат который должен быть

Comment: У вас 4 значения и две одинаковые даты. К какой дате должны относиться значения 56 и 76?